# google-play-billing-validator: Giving back: 'Invalid response, please check \'Verifier\' configuration or the statusCode above'

Tags: node.js, google-play-services, in-app-billing, acknowledgepurchase

It seems that when trying to acknowledging the receipt using the npm package, I am getting the error:

```
{ isSuccessful: false,
  errorCode: 400,
  errorMessage:
   'Invalid response, please check \'Verifier\' configuration or the statusCode above' }
```

I am passing the data as mentioned below:

```
{
        packageName: packageName,
        productId: productId,
        purchaseToken: purchaseToken,
        developerPayload: 'Acknowledged Purchase Successfully'
    }
```

I am facing the same issue mentioned in the link: https://github.com/Deishelon/google-play-billing-validator/issues/14

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Billing v2.2+ said:"we have deprecated developer payload"... read more at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/developer-payload.
try this:

```
{
    packageName: packageName,
    productId: productId,
    purchaseToken: purchaseToken,
}
```